# Windows Azure live media encoders provide live transcoding?

Tags: azure, media, rtmp, http-live-streaming, azure-media-services

I have a simple question - I want to stream live video + audio. I would like to use Windows Azure for that (mainly because it seems to provide HLS with AES protection which I have not encounted in opensource solutionsand clear for managers pricing per streaming user) I amtrobuled because of next quote:

> Currently, Media Services does not provide a live transcoding service.
>   You can use one of the following third party live encoders that output
>   RTMP or Smooth Streaming formats: Elemental, Envivio, Cisco, RGP
>   encoders output Smooth Streaming; Adobe Flash Live, Wirecast and
>   Tredek encoders output RTMP.

And a few lines after

> You can deliver your live stream in any of the following formats:
>   Smooth Streaming, DASH and HLS. When doing live streaming, HLS is
>   packaged dynamically and the default HLS packaging ratio is 3 Smooth
>   fragments to 1 HLS segment (3:1).
>   ...
>   Configure a live transcoder.
>
> Every time you reconfigure the transcoder, call the Reset method on
>   the channel.

So no transcoding is provided yet I shall set up a transcoder... What? How?

In FFmpeg there are 2 types  of transcoding

1. from one encoded data format to another (say PCM raw data to encoded MP3 frames)
2. from one frame/packet type to another (say MP4 frames of already encoded audio/video to FLV frames format with same encoded data in them)

Do they try to tell me that they provide frames repacking from RTMP to HLS yet no live encoding into another compression type (say from Speex audio to AAC)?

Answer (score 1):

As I answered on your another post, you can use tool like Wirecast 6 to encode your live stream and push the stream into Azure Ingest URL. We will give you a publish URL that could dynamically package content into HLS, Smooth Streaming and DASH.

For more information, please refer to this post: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/10/getting-started-with-live-streaming-using-the-azure-management-portal/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The second type of transcoding you describe can be better named transpackaging because no video coding is done.

Transcoding is not provided. Transpackaging is provided.